# How to refresh an online website mirror created with `wget --mirror`?

Tags: unix, wget

One month ago, I used "[wget --mirror](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-mirroring-180)" to create a mirror of our public website for temporary use during an upcoming scheduled maintenance window. Our primary website runs  HTML, PHP & MySQL, but the mirror just needs to be HTML-only, no dynamic-content, PHP or database needed.

The following command will create a simple, online mirror of our website:

```
wget --mirror http://www.example.org/
```

Note that the [Wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) says `--mirror` "is currently equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`" (The human-readable equivalent is `--recursive --timestamping --level=inf --no-remove-listing.

Now it's a month later, and much of the website content has changed. I want wget to check all the pages, and download any pages which have changed. However, this isn't working.

My question:

What do I need to do to refresh the mirror of the website, short of deleting the directory and re-running the mirror?

The top level file at http://www.example.org/index.html has not changed, but there are many other files which *have* changed.

I thought all I needed to do was to re-run `wget --mirror`, because `--mirror` implies the flags `--recursive` "specify recursive download" and `--timestamping` "Don't re-retrieve files unless newer than local." I thought this would check all of the pages and only retrieve files which are newer then my local copies. Am I wrong?

However, wget doesn't recurse the site on the second try. 'wget --mirror' will check http://www.example.org/index.html , notice that this page did not change, and then stop.

```
--2010-06-29 10:14:07--  http://www.example.org/
Resolving www.example.org (www.example.org)... 10.10.6.100
Connecting to www.example.org (www.example.org)|10.10.6.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Server file no newer than local file "www.example.org/index.html" -- not retrieving.

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2010-06-29 10:14:08--  http://www.example.org/robots.txt
Connecting to www.example.org (www.example.org)|10.10.6.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 136 [text/plain]
Saving to: “www.example.org/robots.txt”

     0K                                                       100% 6.48M=0s
2010-06-29 10:14:08 (6.48 MB/s) - "www.example.org/robots.txt" saved [136/136]

--2010-06-29 10:14:08--  http://www.example.org/news/gallery/image-01.gif
Reusing existing connection to www.example.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 40741 (40K) [image/gif]
Server file no newer than local file "www.example.org/news/gallery/image-01.gif" -- not retrieving.

FINISHED --2010-06-29 10:14:08--
Downloaded: 1 files, 136 in 0s (6.48 MB/s)
```

Comment: depending what you are mirroring, you might be able to use rsync instead of wget.  Typically available from big archive sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following workaround seems to work for now. It forcibly deletes /index.html , which forces wget to check all child links again. However, shouldn't wget check all child links automatically?

```
rm www.example.org/index.html && wget --mirror http://www.example.org/
```

Comment: This did the trick for me too.  It is cycling through the files with 304 for most.. but downloading some.. (I hope all that has changed)

Answer (score -1):

```
wget –mirror –w 3 –p –P c:\wget_files\example2 ftp://username:password@ftp.yourdomain.com
```

This is how I do it on a Windows-based machine
[http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Services/Website-Mirroring-With-wget/1/](https://web.archive.org/web/20190702180206/https://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Services/Website-Mirroring-With-wget/1/)

You can change the path to your directory structure, try downloading all content via FTP and see if that helps.

I also use another utility on Windows "AllwaySync" works superbly.

Comment: This is a HTTP webserver, running HTML, PHP & MySQL. I am mirroring the site as flat HTML (No PHP or MySQL are needed on the mirror). There is no FTP access to this box.

Answer (score -2):

I use the --mirror switch to do exactly what you are asking about, which does indeed cause wget to only download newer files recursively. Specifically, my command line (sanitized) is:

```
/usr/bin/wget -v --mirror ftp://user:password@site/ -o /var/log/webmirror -P /var/WebSites
```

Comment: Seems that my wget is getting hung-up on the the fact that 'index.html' doesn't change. Your situation may be a little different, because there is no equivalent to my index.html file. Correct?

Comment: @Stefan, I've just realised that I'm using wget via FTP, not HTTP. That is no doubt why mine is behaving differently. It's been a while since I set this up but I have a vague recollection of having issues when using HTTP.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use:

```
wget -r -l inf -N http://www.example.org/
```

Comment: That results in the same behavior. Those options are already implied by `-m` or `--mirror`. The manual says  is currently equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`.